# How to change the color of the rectangle part by mouse click in HTML, JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Task: When you move the mouse cursor over any part of the rectangle, the color of the given section changes or is deleted by clicking.

```css
.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #9acd32;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

I understand how to change the whole background by clicking the mouse in js, but I do not know how to do this on a certain section of this figure. The area with variable color of the square shape, height and width can be changed.

How can this be implemented using HTML, JS? What methods are needed for this?
or can this task be solved only with the figure drawn in Canvasa'e and its functions?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish. What do you mean by "section"? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: @Koas, By "section" I mean any part of a rectangle.

Comment: You can't change the background color of only a section of a div. What are you trying to do? Maybe some context would bring up new ideas.

Comment: I know how to change the background color of a div on a click, but I do not know how to change the color of any part of a div.  the figure itself can be performed using SVG, Canvas. How to do this using HTML, JS or Canvas?

Comment: @Koas, here's what I wanted to see https://jsfiddle.net/5rgcs9c3/

Answer (score 2):

By inserting jQuery the rectangle changes its color on hover and clicking on it removes it. Here is how to do it:

```js
$( "#squareID" ).click(function() {
  $( ".square" ).remove();
});
$( "#squareID" ).mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css("background", "#456545");
});
$( "#squareID" ).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).css("background", "#9ACD32");
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #9acd32;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="squareID" class="square"></div>
```

Further down your request is impossible to perform unless you bring light to the question again.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change any section of `<div class="square"></div>` cause it is whole.

But you can add other `divs` and with click you can change their style hidden to visible.

Also you can check http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/

Answer (score 0):

if you use a SVG you should be able to do that with simple css, 
pretty much you can target anything in a SVG, [here an example](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/mouseover-effects-svgs).
As per example you can use {SVG element selector}:hover to change css attribute with mouse over, or following the same concept you can use document.querySelector({SVG element selector}) to addEventListener('click',...).

I do not  think you can do it easily just with simple HTML